# Let's promote a Healthy(-ier) Beta

Tags: discussion

See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento

Ahead of the "Let's get critical" monthly site review, we need to get out there and promote a healthier beta.

Right now we're falling behind in two critical areas:

**77% Answered, Needs 90%:**

> Needs Work – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some
>   work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask
>   questions they usually get a good answer.

**Higher Reputation:**

> Needs Work – Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in
>   moderating the site. We recommend: 150 users with 200+ rep (currently
>   59 users with 200+ rep) 10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 1 user
>   with 2,000+ rep) 5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 0 users with
>   3,000+ rep)

Sonassi will break 3000 this week. I'm working on getting to 2000 by the end of next month - 5 or 6 others are in that hunt as well.

But we can encourage faster growth:

- More answer upvotes - upvote some answers that aren't your own. Encourage some of less engaged users on the site by giving them a reward for actually making an effort.
- More *question* upvotes - do your part to upvote interesting questions.

Additionally, Fabian Blechschmidt has been doing a great job of poking old unanswered questions for a response from the OP. I think we can all do a little more to police this.

There may be little reward (read: accepted answer) to digging up old questions, but a word of encouragement - the tough problems posted in Unanswered may still be unsolved. Today I had an accept on an unanswered from January. Everything contributes to driving up the % of answered questions on-site.

In short - the more questions answered, more upvotes, and we're well on our way to a healthier beta.

Comment: There are lots of questions where the poster will never be here again and there are nice answer. Is it possible to accept a solution somehow? Can the moderator? I didn't read the moderator guide yet to be honest.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - unfortunately not, there's no auto-accept or forced accept. So a lot of good answers never get recognition as an accept; but they will benefit from an upvote if the community at large likes the answer

Comment: But this doesn't help the beta criterias :-)

Comment: A site can stay in BETA much longer than the 90 day window - basically as long as it takes. So I wouldn't worry too much

Comment: It's not so much a worry to me as it is making sure the  key users stay vigilant. We can't force accepts - but we can poke and encourage. Basically, keep doing what we're doing.

Comment: Upvoting good answers will help us toward our other goal - promoting the good answerers.